# Update AWS opensearch "Max clause count" attribute via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to update Opensearch "Max clause count" via terraform, but I didn't find a terraform resource that contains this attribute.

[image: Opensearch Cluster settings]

That's the code of my resource:

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "discovery" {
  domain_name           = var.region == "us-east-1" ? "${var.namespace}-${var.service}-${var.env}-domain" : "${var.service}-${var.env}-${var.region_prefix}-domain"
  elasticsearch_version = "OpenSearch_1.3"

  cluster_config {
    instance_type            = "c6g.2xlarge.elasticsearch"
    instance_count           = 6
    dedicated_master_count   = 3
    dedicated_master_enabled = true
    dedicated_master_type    = "m6g.xlarge.elasticsearch"
    zone_awareness_enabled   = true
    zone_awareness_config {
      availability_zone_count = 2
    }
  }
```

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set them using [advanced_options](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticsearch_domain#advanced_options) as explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/createupdatedomains.html#createdomain-configure-advanced-options).

Also, if you have an existing domain with those options, you can use AWS CLI's [describe-domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opensearch/describe-domain.html) to check how exactly `AdvancedOptions` are defined.